# Most efficient way to return Column name in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` `df` that contains 4 different `columns`. For every `row` theres a `value` thats of importance. I want to return the `Column name` where that `value` is displayed. So for the `df` below I want to return the `Column` name when the value 2 is labelled.

```
d = ({
    'A' : [2,0,0,2],     
    'B' : [0,0,2,0],
    'C' : [0,2,0,0],            
    'D' : [0,0,0,0], 
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  2  0  0  0
1  0  0  2  0
2  0  2  0  0
3  2  0  0  0
```

So it would be `A,C,B,A`

I'm doing this via

```
m = (df == 2).idxmax(axis=1)[0]
```

And then changing the row. But this isn't very efficient.

I'm also hoping to produce the output as a `Series` from `pandas df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.dot`:

```
df.astype(bool).dot(df.columns).str.cat(sep=',')
```

Or,

```
','.join(df.astype(bool).dot(df.columns))
```

```
'A,C,B,A'
```

Or, as a list:

```
df.astype(bool).dot(df.columns).tolist()
['A', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

...or a Series:

```
df.astype(bool).dot(df.columns)

0    A
1    C
2    B
3    A
dtype: object
```

Comment: If there are multiple false value in a column, it merges the column,Suppose If a column A is having two false at index 0 and 3 it will give AD.Is there any way to separate those column by a separator

Comment: @MagentoLearner use `df.astype(bool).dot(df.columns+',').str.rstrip(',')`